# How to implement callbacks in Java

Tags: asynchronous, callback

I have a class called CommunicationManager which is responsible for communication with server.

It includes methods `login()` and `onLoginResponse()`. In case of user login the method `login()` has to be called and when the server responds the method `onLoginResponse()` is executed.

What I want to do is to bind actions with user interface. In the GUI class I created an instance of CommunicationManager called `mCommunicationManager`. From GUI class the `login()` method is simply called by the line

```
mCommunicationManager.login();
```

What I don't know how to do is binding the method from GUI class to `onLoginResponse()`. For example if the GUI class includes the method `notifyUser()` which displays the message received from theserver.

I would really appreciate if anyone could show how to bind methods in order to execute the method from GUI class (ex. `GUI.notifyUser()`) when the instance of the class `mCommunicationManager` receives the message from the server and the method `CommunicationManager.onLoginResponse()` is executed.

Thanks!

Comment: why there's nobody said about http call for this callback function that involve swing?

Comment: Question from a newbie. Why can you do System.out.print(mCommunicationManager.login()); (assume, printing the message from the server is the task) ? I understand the use case in a multi threaded model but can't visualize login scenario in a multi threaded model.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's two patterns here I can see you using. One is the [publish/subscribe or observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) mentioned by Pete. I think this is probably what you want, but seeing as the question mentions binding a method for later execution, I thought I should mention the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

The Command pattern is basically a work-around for the fact that java does not treat methods (functions) as first class objects and it's thus impossible to pass them around. Instead, you create an interface that can be passed around and that encapsulates the necessary information about how to call the original method.

So for your example:

```
 interface Command {
     public void execute();
 }
```

and you then pass in an instance of this command when you execute the `login()` function (untested, I always forget how to get anonymous classes right):

```
 final GUI target = this;
 command = new Command() {
     @Override
     public void execute() {
         target.notifyUser();
     }
 };
 mCommunicationManager.login(command);
```

And in the login() function (manager saves reference to command):

```
public void login() {
    command.execute();
}
```

edit:
I should probably mention that, while this is the general explanation of how it works, in Java there is already some plumbing for this purpose, namely the `ActionListener` and related classes (`actionPerformed()` is basically the `execute()` in `Command`). These are mostly intended to be used with the AWT and/or Swing classes though, and thus have features specific to that use case.

Answer (score 3):

The idiom used in Java to achieve callback behaviour is Listeners. Construct an interface with methods for the events you want, have a mechanism for registering listener object with the source of the events. When an event occurs, call the corresponding method on each registered listener. This is a common pattern for AWT and Swing events; for a randomly chosen example see [FocusListener](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) and the corresponding [FocusEvent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusEvent.html) object.

Note that all the events in Java AWT and Swing inherit ultimately from [EventObject](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html), and the convention is to call the listener `SomethingListener` and the event `SomethingEvent`. Although you can get away with naming your code whatever you like, it's easier to maintain code which sticks with the conventions of the platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the swt-snippets (look at the listeners)

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/

or you use the runnable class , by overwritting the run method with your 'callback'-code when you create an instance

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Java does not support method binding or delegates like C# does.

You may have to implement this via Interfaces (e.g. like Command listener.).

Maybe this website will be helpful:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip10.html