# Thread class and pass information to main activity class into TextView

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I would like to make method onSenzorChange run into thread. To run more smooth. And get information of x axis everytime change. And pass it to main class (Activity) into TextView.

MainActivity class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;
    TestOfPassUIThread t;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        t = new TestOfPassUIThread(this);
    }
    public void onStart(View view) {
        t.register();
    }
}
```

TestOfPassUIThread class ( not an activity or anything )

```
public class TestOfPassUIThread implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor sensor;

    public TestOfPassUIThread (Context context) {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    }
    public void register(){
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    public void unregister() {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
    // Want this method be in Thread
    //How can I do this ?
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float xAxis = event.values[0];
        // And I want it to display in TextView!
        // In main activity would be textView.setText("" + xAxis);
        //How to pass it to MainActivity class ?
    }
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve writing on the textview, the following is one way to do it. (you may wanna read about callbacks, check [How to implement callbacks in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476170/how-to-implement-callbacks-in-java)).

As for accessing the UI thread from the background, there multiple ways to do it as well (check: [Running code in main thread from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123621/running-code-in-main-thread-from-another-thread)).

For why we used a `HandlerThread` below, you can read about it here: [Acclerometer Sensor in Separate Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513352/acclerometer-sensor-in-separate-thread).

So your listener becomes:

```
public abstract class TestOfPassUIThread implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager   sensorManager;
    private Sensor          sensor;
    private HandlerThread   handlerThread;
    private Context         context;
    private Runnable        uiRunnable;

    private float           xAxis;

    public TestOfPassUIThread (Context context) {
        this.context    = context;
        sensorManager   = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService (Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor          = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor (Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    }

    public void register () {
        initUiRunnable ();

        handlerThread   = new HandlerThread ("sensorHandler");
        handlerThread.start ();

        sensorManager.registerListener (
            this,
            sensor,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL,
            new Handler (handlerThread.getLooper ())
        );
    }

    public void unregister () {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener (this);

        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                handlerThread.quitSafely ();
                return;
            }
            handlerThread.quit ();
        } finally {
            uiRunnable = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged (SensorEvent event) {
        xAxis = event.values [0];

        // your other background operations

        ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread (uiRunnable);

        // your other background operations
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged (Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    private void initUiRunnable () {
        uiRunnable = new Runnable () {

            @Override
            public void run () {
                // ...... your other UI operations

                fillTextView (xAxis);

                // ...... your other UI operations
            }
        };
    }

    public abstract void fillTextView (float xAxis);
}
```

And your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView           textView;
    private TestOfPassUIThread t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById (R.id.textView);

        t = new TestOfPassUIThread (this) {

            @Override
            public void fillTextView (float xAxis) {
                textView.setText ("Current xAxis: " + xAxis);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume () {
        super.onResume ();
        t.register ();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause () {
        t.unregister ();
        super.onPause ();
    }
}
```

Also, when you override LifeCycle methods of Activities such as `onStart`, `onResume` etc..., make sure to call the `super.lifeCycleMethod`.

---

Comment: Thank you for this. Got one question about " Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 ". Is there anything that is only in API higher of Jelly Bean ? Or could I do here ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1 ?

Comment: And " sensorManager.registerListener (this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL,new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper ()) ); " in this line new Handler cosing me error ( crash ).

Comment: @Mjafko, question1: the condition that I wrote is handling the version you say... question2: what's the exception?

Comment: @Mjafko, check my edit, I forgot to start the `handlerThread.start ()` on the `register ()` method, which was causing an NullPointerException. (I just tested it, it works now ;))

Comment: @Mjafko, I also fixed your activity callbacks missing `super.onStart`.. If my answer helped you don't hesitate to upvote and mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: One more question if I may. Got problem to pause it and start it again after. Got "Only one Looper may be created per thread" am I missing something ?

Comment: @Mjafko, give me some time, I'll run this code and fix it

Comment: Thank your so much. I am kinda new at this. Trying to understand and figure it out :)