# How to pass Adapter to Model class in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In my application i want use **multiple** **timer** into `recyclerview`.
For not reset timer when scrolling on `recyclerview`'s items i write **CountDown** timer into model class.

For this i should call `notifyItemChanged` into **model class**.
But i don't know how can i send adapter to model class!

**My model class :**

```
data class Today(
    @SerializedName("auction_status")
    val auctionStatus: String = "", // accept
    @SerializedName("base_price")
    val basePrice: Int = 0, // 48000
    @SerializedName("bid_number")
    val bidNumber: String = "", // 1
    @SerializedName("calculate_end")
    val calculateEnd: Long = 0, // -4458
    @SerializedName("can_offer_before")
    val canOfferBefore: Int = 0, // 1
    @SerializedName("capacity")
    val capacity: Int = 0, // 15
    @SerializedName("current_price")
    val currentPrice: Int = 0, // 112000
    @SerializedName("discount")
    val discount: Int = 0, // 160000
    @SerializedName("end")

    var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer? = null,
    var currentVal: String

) {
    init {
        countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(calculateEnd * 1000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                var seconds = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toInt()
                val hours = seconds / (60 * 60)
                val tempMint = seconds - hours * 60 * 60
                val minutes = tempMint / 60
                seconds = tempMint - minutes * 60
                currentVal =
                    String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + String.format(
                        "%02d",
                        minutes
                    ) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds)
                // call adapter.notifyItemChanged(..) here
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                //here  you should call the adapter.notifyItemChanged(..) function with the position of this model in the model list
            }
        }.start()
    }
}
```

**Adapter codes**:

```
class AuctionsTodayAdapter(val context: Context, val model: MutableList<Today>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AuctionsTodayAdapter.MyHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_main_list, parent, false)
        val holder = MyHolder(view)

        //holder.setIsRecyclable(false)

        return holder
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return model.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int) {

    }

override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: MyHolder) {
    var position = holder.adapterPosition
    val modelUse = model[position]
    holder.setData(modelUse)
}

override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: MyHolder) {
    if (holder.countTimer != null) {
        holder.countTimer.cancel()
    }
}

    inner class MyHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var newCountDownTimer: CountDownTimer? = null

        lateinit var rowMain_timer: TextView

        init {
            rowMain_timer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowMain_timer)
        }

        fun setData(model: Today) {
            model.image.let {
                Glide.with(context)
                    .load(Constants.MAIN_BASE_URL + it)
                    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE))
                    .into(itemView.rowMain_img)
            }
            model.title.let { itemView.rowMain_title.text = it }
        }
}
```

**Activity codes:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var apisList: ApisList
    private lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit
    private lateinit var todayAdapter: AuctionsTodayAdapter
    private val todayModel: MutableList<Today> = mutableListOf()
    private lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //Initialize
        retrofit = ApiClient.instance
        apisList = retrofit.create(ApisList::class.java)
        todayAdapter = AuctionsTodayAdapter(themedContext, todayModel)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(themedContext)
        //RecyclerView
        main_list.setHasFixedSize(true)
        main_list.layoutManager = layoutManager
        main_list.adapter = todayAdapter

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) getData(1, 10)
    }

    private fun getData(page: Int, limit: Int) {
        main_loader.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val call = apisList.getAuctionsToday(page, limit)
        call.let {
            it.enqueue(object : Callback<AuctionsTodayResponse> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<AuctionsTodayResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    main_loader.visibility = View.GONE
                    Log.e("auctionsTodayList", t.message)
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<AuctionsTodayResponse>, response: Response<AuctionsTodayResponse>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        response.body()?.let { itBody ->
                            main_loader.visibility = View.GONE
                            if (itBody.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
                                todayModel.clear()
                                todayModel.addAll(itBody.res.today)
                                todayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

How can i it?

Comment: You need to move the CountDownTimer at least to the Adapter or to the Activity. From there, you need to maintain a list of CountDownTimer paired with your model. Don't pollute your model with CountDownTimer.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך , when use countDownTimer into adapter when scrolling items timer has reset!

Comment: you should add it in your activity

Comment: @Praveen, how can i it? can you help me and send to me code? please

Comment: show your acivity class and could you please specify your question

Comment: @Praveen, show me update post

Comment: @Praveen can you help me?

Comment: i don't understand your question, why you using CountDown timer ? is that for  calling notifyItemChanged ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190353/discussion-between-praveen-and-jake-warton).

Answer (score 0):

You can either build an interface in model class (which needs to be initialized in your activity) and use it to send information by implementing it in adapter. Another way is to make your own callback and listener. Follow these links; [Java Interfaces](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Interfaces) , [Callback & Listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476170/how-to-implement-callbacks-in-java/1477229#1477229).

You can see more guides and examples here: [Beginning Android Resources](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Beginning-Android-Resources)

Answer (score 0):

**call this method from   onResponse(..)**

```
  fun recyclerScroll(){

 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

                        if (dy > 0) {

                           // recyclerview is scrolling up
                          // your code for  cancel timer

                        } else if(layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0){

                            // recyclerview is not scrolling 
                          // start timer

                        }
                     else{
                         // recyclerview is scrolling down
                          // your code for cancel timer
                        }

                    }

                    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.isEnabled = gridLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0
                    }

                })

 }
```

and call it from adapter

```
(context as Your_Activity_Name).recyclerScroll()
```

Comment: you say use timer into activity? i want change items UI with timer. then i should use this into adapter

Comment: move above code to a method and you can call it from adapter

Comment: how can i it? can you send code with my above codes ? please